# How to configure only password based ssh for all hosts

Tags: ssh

I want to disable public-private key  based authentication for ssh server. Only want to use password based ssh client login. How to configure that? any help?

Content of my /etc/ssh/sshd_config file is following
Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf

```
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2
# For this to work you will also need host keys in 

/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
PasswordAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

Content of my /etc/ssh/ssd_config file is following

```
Include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf

Host *
   PasswordAuthentication yes
   HostbasedAuthentication no
   StrictHostKeyChecking no
   UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
```

Comment: Can you provide us your OpenSSH server configuration file?  I assume your using OpenSSH.  You might want to edit and clarify your question if that isn’t the case.

Comment: sure. Which config file? sshd_config or ssh_config?

Comment: Which every configuration file is actually being used.  You can start your server in verbose mode to determine the location of the configuration file if you don't already know.

Comment: Just updated the posts with the content of my sshd_config and ssh_config file. Kindly have a look

Comment: What exactly makes you think public-private key authentication is enabled on this server?  Are you the Administrator of this server?

Comment: I am basically trying to deploy scripts on some mininet hosts. So yes, I am the administrator. I am trying to connect without ssh key. I just want to use password based ssh connection.

Comment: Have you tried to connect using a password.  When you attempted to authenticate with a password what did the server log indicate? It will be necessary to look at the verbose logs for the server to determine what actually is happening.  You should also add ** PubkeyAuthentication no** in your active configuration file and restart the OpenSSH service on the server.  Once you do that provide the verbose logs of that indicates the connection attempt of a user